# What causes Apache "Request body read timeout" errors?

Tags: apache

The server is `Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)` and the browser is `Firefox 30.0`, but this is a general question. It refers to lines like this in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Fri Jun 20 17:42:16 2014] [info] [client 67.174.61.70] Request body read timeout
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with timeouts. As Luke mentioned on an earlier response, it is related with mod_reqtimeout configuration. In my case slow connections caused ssl handshake to fail...

I solved it by increasing the timeout for the header...

**Solution**

You just need to edit mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf on the apache configuration folder

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
      RequestReadTimeout header=60,minrate=500  
</IfModule>
```

(Increase the time after header to something long enough)

*Note*: If the conf file is not present on the dir, then the mod is not enabled, and this is not the solution for your problem.

Comment: For me `reqtimeout_module` was written in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` as line `LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so`, but deleting that line and restarting `httpd` didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was mod_reqtimeout - this plugin sits there and checks that the request is coming in at an adequate rate and that the user isn't trying to perform a DOS attack. If it is an internal server you might want to just disable it if your having trouble.

If you are proxying I would also check the timeouts on mod_proxy. These can be set in the ProxyPass tag.

If this doesn't help, you might want to set your trace level to debug and review the error log.

Comment: Where do I put that ProxyPass tag?

Comment: In your apache config. Here is an example config https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension (under Enabling SSL Reverse-Proxy Support) and here is an example of it being set https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html (under workers).